# Layout for separate 'App' and 'BackgroundJobs' packages

Tags: haskell, background-process, yesod

I'm developing a Yesod app in which many app requests will cause data to be fetched from 3rd-party APIs.  The fetched data will only be used during subsequent requests -- that is, the request that triggers an API callout can finish without waiting for the callout to finish.

It's important that a given piece of data `xyz` not be fetched and stored twice, but the nature of the app is that multiple clients will often become interested in `xyz` at the same moment.  If I have each app thread querying the database to see whether `xyz` has already been fetched, I will start to see concurrency-related issues even at modest scale.  Even if I were to write a bunch of code to handle the concurrency-related integrity issues -- not fun, and it would be hard to be sure I'd covered all cases -- it's bad practice to abuse expensive database queries this way.

It seems to me a good alternative would be to have all App threads publish requests ("Make sure xyz data has been fetched") to an AMQP queue, to which one or more 'background worker'-type processes would subscribe.

In [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/yesodweb/UW5tZltjHJI/62O7PnZbGPcJ) Greg Weber suggests a dual-package layout in which both packages have 'my Persistent layer' as a dependency.  He mentions that I could use symlinks or `hs-source-dir`s to avoid maintaining two copies of the 'Persistent layer' code.

On a high level what Greg is describing makes perfect sense to me, but I'm relatively new to Haskell and I fear it would take me a while to figure out the particulars.  Can someone lay it out for me in more detail?

- How should the package directories be laid out?  (Which files, exactly, constitute my Persistent layer?)
- What should the .cabal files look like?
- Once they're laid out that way, do I need to change the way my (scaffolded site) source files are importing my Persistent models?

Another part of it is: How would you recommend writing the BackgroundJobs process?  I've never written production Haskell code except within Yesod's scaffolding.  I get it in broad outlines -- I'll just write a `main`, within which I'll subscribe to the message queue and, upon each message, do my callout/processing/storing -- but do I need to worry about e.g. manual forking to make sure the process doesn't block while waiting for a callout to finish?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm off the starting block, using the general approach Erik suggested -- I just added a 2nd `executable` block to my scaffolded project's .cabal file.  Here's the corresponding source file ("`daemon.hs`" in Erik's formulation):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Import
import Yesod.Default.Config
import qualified Database.Persist
import qualified Database.Persist.Store as DPS (runPool, createPoolConfig, loadConfig, applyEnv)
import Settings
import Model
import Data.Conduit (runResourceT)
import Control.Monad.Logger (runStdoutLoggingT)
import Debug.Trace
import Data.Text as T

runQueries = do
    res <- getBy $ UniqueFoo "bar"
    trace ("\nresult: " ++ show res ++ "\n\n") $ return ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
    conf <- (fromArgs parseExtra)
    dbconf <- withYamlEnvironment "config/postgresql.yml" (appEnv conf)
              DPS.loadConfig >>= DPS.applyEnv
    p <- DPS.createPoolConfig (dbconf :: Settings.PersistConfig)
    runStdoutLoggingT $ runResourceT $ DPS.runPool dbconf runQueries p
```

I based it on the first example on [this Yesod wiki entry](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Using-Database.Persist.runPool-without-Foundation) -- modified so the executable expects an environment flag.

Comment: By the way, this was using Yesod 1.19.  I've since updated to 1.2 and a couple tiny tweaks to this code were required -- all were easy/obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I have a application which consists of a webapp and a separate daemon process that collects data and inserts it into the database that it shares with the webapp.

I basically have all the code in the same source code tree and have two files which define `main :: IO ()`, one called `webapp.hs` and the other called `daemon.hs`. I then have the cabal file define and build the two separate executables.

Unfortunately I can't share the code as its an internal project I'm doing in my day job.